# How to access the value of a property of an object using a function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, object

Just learning `JS` and I'm working through some tutorials. I've ran into a question that I have not been able to solve. The question is:

> Write a function called `getValue()`. It should take two inputs: an `object` and a `key`. It should return the corresponding `value` for that `key` within the `object`. Keep in mind that this should be a one-line `function`.

I know you can access this with `objectName.property` but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this within a `function`.

Again, very new to `JS`. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are facing the property accessor.

Comment: Have a look at the bracket syntax to access object properties.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors as Nina said. Something like this would be enough: https://jsfiddle.net/u3dtskx4/ . Remember to check if the key exists in the object, else it will throw an error.

Comment: object.property
object["property"]

Comment: @briosheje just a pointer, you do not need ternary operator in `getValue`. `-1` can be a valid value. just do `return obj[key]`.

Comment: @Rajesh: you're right, it was just a way to don't return undefined and return something else to manipulate later :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, you need a [`function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function) with a name, which is

```
function getValue() {
}
```

Then you need the parameters, like `object` and `key`, which are written in the head of the function.

```
function getValue(object, key) {
}
```

After that, you need to [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) something. This stops the function as well.

```
function getValue(object, key) {
    return;
}
```

At last, you need the value from the object with a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with bracket notation, it take the object and a variable, or a value for the key, like

```
object[key]
```

and together in the function, you get then

```
function getValue(object, key) {
    return object[key];
}
```

In the case, you supply a key, which is not in the object, you get [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) as result.

Comment: As I have commented before, ` || null` is not required. `return object[key]` is more than enough as `false` or `0` can be valid values and adding `|| null` will cause other issues. Being a generic function, we should try to keep data processing to minimum.

Comment: @Rajesh, you are right. the `null` was not from me, sorry.

Comment: Yup. Just saw the edit history. Also nicely explained. Also if you are free, you should add `WHY`. There are many cases where SO provides the solution and people use it without knowing the reason for it. I have seen people doing `var a = []; data.map(x=>{a.push(x)})`

Comment: You know you are a victim of your own success. Your answers are so accurate and clear that if there is 1 thing that's goes off, it is highlighted. I have commented so many times for correction on your answer and will keep doing in future as well, so please bare with me. And keep being awesome. :-)

Comment: @Rajesh, i appreciate your comments :)

Comment: @NinaScholz thank you for your answer. I appreciate you taking the time to break it down.